# How do I sort a table with non alphabetical values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a non-programmer and want to use the power of SQL to sort my inventory data. Here's the sample table that I have.

```
Product | Option_1_Value
Apple | 1 gallon
Apple | Apple
Apple | 30ml
Apple | 4 gallons
Apple | 10ml
Apple | 100ml
Apple | 500ml
Apple | 1 liter
Banana| 4 gallons
Banana| 1 gallon
Banana| Banana
Banana| 10ml
Banana| 100ml
Banana| 500ml
Banana| 1 liter
```

I want to turn this data to this. How can I query my table to have a result like this below

```
Product | Option_1_Value
Apple | Apple
Apple | 10ml
Apple | 30ml
Apple | 100ml
Apple | 500ml
Apple | 1 liter
Apple | 1 gallon
Apple | 4 gallons
Banana| Banana
Banana| 10ml
Banana| 100ml
Banana| 500ml
Banana| 1 liter
Banana| 1 gallon
Banana| 4 gallons
```

Comment: 1. Are you expecting the sort to know the difference between number part and word part? 2. Are you expecting it to know the difference between liters and gallons?

Comment: Yes. It needs to go from low volume to largest volume. Some have this data: 10ml, 100ml, 500ml, 1 liter, 4 liters, 21 liters

Comment: @samuelmrrsn . . . If I understand correctly, you want the sort to know the difference between milliliters, liters, gallons, and bananas.  That require sophisticated logic that you need to add.  What would be the ordering of 50 liters and 11 gallons?  Oh wait?  Is that imperial gallons or US gallons?

Comment: Is Option_1_Value a singular column in the DB? Or more importantly can, you get it into two columns? If not you are going to have to parse it into two columns.

Comment: The way to go about would be a define a common "currency" and translate all of those values into the common unit(eg: convert everything to metric unit litre) then we can sort by it

Comment: @GordonLinoff The largest size in the dataset 25 kilos. Let's stick to these dataset: 10ml, 30ml, 100ml, 1 liter, 4 liters, 20 liters, 1 gallon, 4 gallons

Comment: @samuelmrrsn you would need to tell all of the possible "metric" values in the list first

Comment: what is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two suggestions - if stick to the datasets given.

If you're on MySQL 8++ or MariaDB 10.3+, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` like this:

```
SET @gal := 3.78541, @lit := 1000; -- setting variable value for gallon & liter.

SELECT Product,option_1_value,
       (CASE WHEN size LIKE '%gallon%' THEN qty*@gal*@lit WHEN size LIKE '%liter%' THEN qty*@lit ELSE qty END)+0 AS size_in_ml 
FROM
   (SELECT *,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(option_1_value,'[A-Za-z]','') AS Qty,
           TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(option_1_value,'[0-9]','')) AS Size 
    FROM myproduct) p
ORDER BY product ASC, size_in_ml ASC;
```

If you're using older MySQL version:

```
SET @gal := 3.78541, @lit := 1000; -- setting variable value for gallon & liter.
SELECT Product,option_1_value,
      (CASE WHEN size LIKE '%gallon%' THEN qty*@gal*@lit WHEN size LIKE '%liter%' THEN qty*@lit ELSE qty END)+0 AS size_in_ml 
FROM
(SELECT *,
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(option_1_value,'gallons',''),'gallon',''),'ml',''),'liter','')+0 AS Qty,
       SUBSTRING(option_1_value,LEAST(IF(LOCATE('g',option_1_value)=0,99,LOCATE('g',option_1_value)),
      IF(LOCATE('l',option_1_value)=0,99,LOCATE('l',option_1_value)),
      IF(LOCATE('m',option_1_value)=0,99,LOCATE('m',option_1_value)))) AS size FROM myproduct) p
ORDER BY product ASC, size_in_ml ASC;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWMqhq3eANcbBeTvsTrF4P/0)

Comment: This works. I'll study it and modify to fit my purpose! Thank you very much for saving me so much time!

Comment: You're welcome @samuelmrrsn . If you need some explanation (especially on the second query), please just drop a comment and I'll gladly explain the logic ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have got all measurable quantities that are liquids, here is a way to do this

```
select *
       ,CAST(option_1_value AS UNSIGNED) as num_val
       ,CAST(option_1_value AS UNSIGNED)*y.mux as sort_val
  from (
        select 'Apple' as product ,'1 gallon' as Option_1_Value    union all
        select 'Apple ','Apple'        union all
        select 'Apple ','30ml'         union all
        select 'Apple ','4 gallons'    union all
        select 'Apple ','10ml'         union all
        select 'Apple ','100ml'        union all
        select 'Apple ','500ml'       union all
        select 'Apple ','1 liter'      union all
        select 'Banana','4 gallons'    union all
        select 'Banana','1 gallon'     union all
        select 'Banana','Banana'       union all
        select 'Banana','10ml'         union all
        select 'Banana','100ml'        union all
        select 'Banana','500ml'        union all
        select 'Banana','1 liter' 
      )x
left join 
     (select 'ml' as unit,0.001 as mux union all
      select 'gallon',3.78541 union all
      select 'gallons',3.78541 union all
      select 'liter',1
      
     )y
   on x.Option_1_Value like concat('%',y.unit,'%')
order by product,sort_val asc


+---------+----------------+---------+----------+
| product | Option_1_Value | num_val | sort_val |
+---------+----------------+---------+----------+
| Apple   | Apple          |       0 |          |
| Apple   | 10ml           |      10 |  0.01000 |
| Apple   | 30ml           |      30 |  0.03000 |
| Apple   | 100ml          |     100 |  0.10000 |
| Apple   | 500ml          |     500 |  0.50000 |
| Apple   | 1 liter        |       1 |  1.00000 |
| Apple   | 1 gallon       |       1 |  3.78541 |
| Apple   | 4 gallons      |       4 | 15.14164 |
| Apple   | 4 gallons      |       4 | 15.14164 |
| Banana  | Banana         |       0 |          |
| Banana  | 10ml           |      10 |  0.01000 |
| Banana  | 100ml          |     100 |  0.10000 |
| Banana  | 500ml          |     500 |  0.50000 |
| Banana  | 1 liter        |       1 |  1.00000 |
| Banana  | 1 gallon       |       1 |  3.78541 |
| Banana  | 4 gallons      |       4 | 15.14164 |
| Banana  | 4 gallons      |       4 | 15.14164 |
+---------+----------------+---------+----------+
```

dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9e5169e9ec7561c307454b4e90351e5f

Comment: Thanks, but this solution requires me to input every flavor in the From clause.

Comment: A better option would be replace the block y with a regular table and store all of the possible combinations in there. Since this is a demo i kept it in the body of the query itself.